# how to link urls path with views in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, e-commerce, django-urls

`I am developing an ecommerce website on Django I need help on how to link URLs with the views.

Here is the URL:

```
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product detail'),
]
```

This is the view:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product

def category_detail(request, slug):
    category =  get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    products = category.products.all()

    return render(request, 'store/category_detail.html', {
        'category': category,
        'products': products,
    })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46r73.png)

Attached is the error I get.

I am expecting to see the web page.

This is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='products', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/product_images/', 
blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_display_price(self):
        return self.price / 100
```

Comment: Share your `Product` model.

Comment: also add the template as text to the question. [edit] the question.

Comment: `name='product detail'` should be `name='product_detail'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I cannot add the template. kindly see the link to the template above.

Answer (score 0):

You used `Category` as name of the field, with a capital `C` (which is not a good idea), hence you should use:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.Category.slug product.slug %}">
```

but this will result in an *N+1* problem. You can better just use the `category` you already passed to the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' category.slug product.slug %}">
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `category` instead of <s>`Category`</s>.